# NetworkManager won't list wireless networks

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 `x64` on a `Acer Aspire F5-572G`.

During the installation I've connected to my wireless network and other networks showed up as well.

After installing all updates, even know it connects automatically to my network, the icon in network manager appears to be as `wired connection`, also no wireless networks show up in the list. No addition drivers for my network card were found.

Comment: try `sudo service network-manager restart` That restarts the network-manager. I have that problem sometimes on my Linux Mint machine but I only see my wifi connection and no other wifi networks

Comment: Interesting thing, it works on Fedora.

Comment: so did my suggestion work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.